# Difference between Mechanize and Capybara (with webmock/webkit/selenium)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Having read tons of documentation on the above, I am a bit confused: is there anything useful that Mechanize can do that Capybara (with webmock/webkit/selenium) cannot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Capybara is more frequently used(http://www.techwars.io/fight/capybara/mechanize/) overall which could mean more community support.

Also, it seems that you can not test remotes with just the basic Capybara, and can with Mechanize, as it has been made a Capybara gem extension here: https://github.com/jeroenvandijk/capybara-mechanize.